# I am new to C++ and struggling to figure out why my code works perfectly but still returns an absurd number after running

Tags: c++

I want to determine if a number is even or odd.
Since i wanted to practice my new knowledge of classes, I wrote a class and built a function to help me with determining whether the number is odd or even.

After compiling and testing my code, it runs perfectly. But after printing out the print statement embedded in the function, it prints a huge number as well.

Why does the program return that number?

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class numbers{

        public:
           int odev(int num)
           {
              if (num % 2 == 0){
                cout << num << " is an even number" << endl;
              }
              else{
                cout << num << " is an odd number" << endl;
              }

           }

            int greatest_number(int fnum, int snum, int tnum)
            {
                if (fnum > snum && fnum > tnum){
                    cout << fnum << " is greatest among these" << endl;
            }
                    else if (snum > fnum && snum > tnum){
                        cout << snum << "is greatest among these" << endl;
                    }
                else{
                    cout << tnum << " is the greatest among these" << endl;
                }
            }
    };
    int main()
    {
        numbers arit;
        float d;

        cout <<"Enter any number: \n> ";
        cin >> d;

        cout << arit.odev(d) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

This is what it shows.
[image: This is what it shows.]

Comment: "my code works perfectly but still returns an absurd number after running" hmmm.

Comment: A seemingly random number is most likely an uninitialized variable.

Comment: You declared a `float` type `d` and then passed this to a method expecting `int`, did you try any debugging?

Comment: You forgot to return a number from `odev`. Your compiler will tell you about silly mistakes like that if you enable warnings.

Comment: `numbers::odev` doesn't return anything, looking at the code i'd make it void and change `cout << arit.odev(d) << endl;` -> `arit.odev(d);`.

Comment: Question aside: There is absolutely no reason to use a class here. What you are doing is completely non-object-oriented. Ask yourself what `numbers` or `arit` are supposed to represent... They are only obfuscations.

Answer (score 5):

The member function `odev` does not return anything even though its return type is `int`. Hence, your program has undefined behavior.

You can fix it by adding a `return` statement or changing the return type to `void` and replacing

```
cout << arit.odev(d) << endl;
```

with

```
arit.odev(d);
```

The member function `greatest_number` suffers from the same problem.

---

You can detect such errors at compile time by turning up the warning level. When I compile the posted code using `g++ -Wall`, I get the following messages.

```
socc.cc: In member function ‘int numbers::odev(int)’:
socc.cc:17:7: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
       }
       ^
socc.cc: In member function ‘int numbers::greatest_number(int, int, int)’:
socc.cc:30:7: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
       }
```